# In two point perspective, why aren't the sides of this rectangle correctly foreshortened?

Tags: perspective

The blue object is a very simple rectangle in two point perspective.[image]
Next I zoom in on it: [image]
When I measure the sides, I see is that the back side is shorter than the front side. It is foreshortened.  The right side is closer to viewer than the left side. I would think the left side should be shorter because it is farther from the viewer.  But it doesn't work.  The left side is longer.  So the farther side is not foreshortened. Isn't this a contradiction?

Where is my logic wrong?

Comment: Simply your intersections dont match your lines.

Comment: If using something like Illustrator, you need to work in *Outline Mode*. In Preview Mode the strokes applied to paths obscure the *actual* path spine. You can't effectively align much manually with any sort of precision in Preview Mode.

Comment: @Scott you can but you have to be comfortable with how smart guides work and keep pressing combos of ctrl+shift

Comment: Hi Scott, I appreciate the tips on using Illustrator.  However, I believe that even if I was more accurate, the observation would still be true.  Have you tried it?  I believe that the answer from @Wrzlprmft is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t see a contradiction.
Closer line segments are only larger under the same angle of viewing.
In your example, the difference between the viewing angles has a larger effect than the distance.
This is roughly because you are closer to the right vanishing point than the left one.

To better see this, let’s take the example to the extreme:
Take any non-quadratic rectangle and place it such that your line of sight goes almost along one of the shorter edges.
You will see something like this:

[image: rectangle seen as described]

Now you go further such that your line of sight is exactly along that edge.
Now every point of that edge is closer to your eye than any point of the opposing edge, yet the length of the projection of that edge in your vision is zero, while the opposite edge has a finite (and thus infinitely larger) length.

Comment: This is the right answer. My answer is more of a sidenote.

Comment: @Wrzlpmft  Thanks for the answer. I get the concept, however I can't see it in your diagram.  I find your diagram hard to understand.  Can you add some more details/explanation/guides to your diagram?

Comment: @Chris: See my edit.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft   Hello, you seem to know a thing or two about  perspective drawing. I'm new to it. Could I ask you some  questions outside of Stack Exchange?  The story is that II hired a professional illustrator to draw some diagrams for an exercise manual.  I think he is accustomed to drawing people standing up, but many of my exercises are lying down.  He told me he is saving difficulty with the perspective.  So, I've  been  studying perspective myself to understand his difficulty.  I have a PhD in physics, so this should not be beyond my capability.  Anyway, could I tell you more by email?

Comment: @Chris: I don’t know that much about perspective drawing, let alone of people. I am only good at finding illustrative counterexamples by taking things to the extreme (PhD in physics and such). I would have to invest as much work as you do, probably more so.

Comment: @Chris. Drawing humans in perspective is quite hard. Takes practice and sometimes also some personal style of simplification so you don't have to draw a Rembrandt every time. Perhaps instead of approaching this as an academic subject you should try looking at books for artists. As a kid I enjoyed [How to Draw Comics the Marvel Way](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+draw+comics+the+marvel+way&ia=images&iax=images)  by Stan Lee and John Buscema. It has some tricks to seeing the body as a collection of boxes. Also maybe look at more advanced stuff like *Dynamic Figure Drawing* by Burne Hogarth.

Comment: Or of course use a real person, images you find online, a wooden figure or a 3D model as reference.

Answer (score 4):

I just think the difference is very small and your drawing isn't precise enough for you to measure it.

Which application did you draw this in and how do you measure?

It looks like the left vanishing point is a tiny bit lower than the right one. I can see the right one is a few pixels above the horizon.

If I take the closeup and stretch it vertically it's easier to see the details.

[image]

Notice how the blue shape is skewed compared to where the red lines actually intersect?

All these little inaccuracies add up.